# Choices.Add with JQuery

Tags: 2013, jquery, dropdown

I am using JQUery to fill a DropDownChoice dynamically, depending on a custom DropDown menu earlier.

However, if I just add the entries by

```
<option value="1">Option X</option>
```

I can't save, because of an internal error. I assume that the DropDownChoice doesn't know the value (which is "correct").

Is there a way, using JQuery, to add the value as a valid choice to the field?

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: You mean you want to add an extra choice in your site column which is of type Choice using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly, what I want! I want it to be temporary though.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself:

Made the field a Lookup field and added the entries the following way:

```
<option value="ItemId">ItemTitle</option>
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates to update `SP.FieldChoice` field properties:

Referred from [SHAREPOINT 2013: How can I read Site column contents and modify them via javascript csom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916316/sharepoint-2013-how-can-i-read-site-column-contents-and-modify-them-via-javascr)

```
function updateFieldChoice(fieldTitle,choiceValues,success,failure) {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var fieldChoice = ctx.castTo(web.get_availableFields().getByTitle(fieldTitle), SP.FieldChoice);
    fieldChoice.set_choices(choiceValues);
    fieldChoice.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            success(fieldChoice)
        },
        failure);
}
```

Usage:

```
var choiceValues = ["Low", "Normal", "Critical"];

SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    updateFieldChoice('RequestStatus',choiceValues,
        function(field){
        console.log('Choice field has been updated'); 
        },
        function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
        });
});
```